# How to read a JSON file as a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I am using python 3.6 and trying to download json file (350 MB) as pandas dataframe using the code below. However, I get the following error:

> ```
> data_json_str = "[" + ",".join(data) + "]
> "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found
> ```

How can I fix the error?

```
import pandas as pd

# read the entire file into a python array
with open('C:/Users/Alberto/nutrients.json', 'rb') as f:
   data = f.readlines()

# remove the trailing "\n" from each line
data = map(lambda x: x.rstrip(), data)

# each element of 'data' is an individual JSON object.
# i want to convert it into an *array* of JSON objects
# which, in and of itself, is one large JSON object
# basically... add square brackets to the beginning
# and end, and have all the individual business JSON objects
# separated by a comma
data_json_str = "[" + ",".join(data) + "]"

# now, load it into pandas
data_df = pd.read_json(data_json_str)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you open the file as binary (`'rb'`), you will get bytes.  How about:

```
with open('C:/Users/Alberto/nutrients.json', 'rU') as f:
```

Also as noted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48614799/7311767) answer you can also use pandas directly like:

```
df = pd.read_json('C:/Users/Alberto/nutrients.json', lines=True)
```

Answer (score 54):

From your code, it looks like you're loading a JSON file which has JSON data on each separate line. [`read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) supports a `lines` argument for data like this:

```
data_df = pd.read_json('C:/Users/Alberto/nutrients.json', lines=True)
```

> **Note**
>   Remove `lines=True` if you have a single JSON object instead of individual JSON objects on each line.

Answer (score 13):

Using the json module you can parse the json into a python object, then create a dataframe from that:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
with open('C:/Users/Alberto/nutrients.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: I used the above code and got "JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 110)"

Comment: No need for `'r'` in my case, though not harming either (untested, just from experience),

Answer (score 1):

if you want to convert it into an *array* of JSON objects, I think this one will do what you want

```
import json
data = []
with open('nutrients.json', errors='ignore') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(json.loads(line))
print(data[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

**The easiest way to read json file using pandas is:**

```
pd.read_json("sample.json",lines=True,orient='columns')
```

**To deal with nested json like this**

> [[{Value1:1},{value2:2}],[{value3:3},{value4:4}],.....]

**Use Python basics**

```
value1 = df['column_name'][0][0].get(Value1)
```

Comment: what is Value1 here? name of the column?

Comment: @Kubra Value1 is key and the corresponding value will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Please the code below

```
#call the pandas library
import pandas as pd
#set the file location as URL or filepath of the json file
url = 'https://www.something.com/data.json'
#load the json data from the file to a pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_json(url, orient='columns')
#display the top 10 rows from the dataframe (this is to test only)
df.head(10)
```

Please review the code and modify based on your need. I have added comments to explain each line of code. Hope this helps!