# Error when reading json file in python: Expected object or value

Tags: python, json

I have this json file saved in my jupyter notebook that I would like to read:

```
[
    {   'category_type': 'c',
        'modification_type': 'fixed',
        'modification_list': 0 ,
        'features_list': ['feature1','feature2']
    },
    {   'category_type': 'continious',
        'modification_type': 'fixed_list',
        'modification_list': 1 ,
        'suffix': '_1',
        'features_list': ['feature3','feature4']
    }
]
```

The file is saved in a folder on the home of jupyter notebook and I am trying to read it using the below code:

```
pd.read_json('folder/file.json', orient='records',encoding='utf-8')
```

but I keep getting this error: ValueError: Expected object or value

Anyone able to help out with this issue please?

Comment: That's not JSON.  JSON uses double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: I get the same error even if I change the single quotes with double quotes..

Comment: According to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/, it's valid json by RFC 7159 if you change the single quotes to double quotes

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48614158/read-json-file-as-pandas-dataframe

Comment: None of the solutions in that link actually work....

Answer (score 0):

To read json as pandas data frame just use these few lines of code. I think that's your problem

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# Load the first sheet of the JSON file into a data frame
data_df = pd.read_json('reviewsclean.json', lines=True)
```