# Is there a more pythonic way to load a text file with json objects into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I've done

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

with open("myjson.json", "r") as f:
    objects = f.readlines()

jlist = []
for o in objects:
    jlist.append(json.loads(o))

df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(jlist))
```

That works and I get the pandas `DataFrame`, but I was wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: I think you will find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48614158/read-json-file-as-pandas-dataframe.

Comment: You can directly call `df = pd.read_json("myjson.json")`.

Answer (score 1):

It can be loaded in a single statement

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('myjson.json', lines=True)
```

`lines=True` indicates that the file consists of one JSON object per line.

You can read more about it here, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html