# How do I export JSON data to CSV using python?

Tags: python, html, json, csv

I'm building a site that, based on a user's input, sorts through JSON data and prints a schedule for them into an html table. I want to give it the functionality that once the their table is created they can export the data to a CSV/Excel file so we don't have to store their credentials (logins & schedules in a database). Is this possible? If so, how can I do it using python preferably?

Comment: you could use pandas. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html, and then export to  csv: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html?highlight=csv#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read json file as pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48614158/read-json-file-as-pandas-dataframe) Also [Writing a pandas DataFrame to CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16923281/843953) Please take the [tour], and read [ask] and [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic). 
[Asking on Stack Overflow is not a substitute for doing your own research.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)

Comment: `pandas` is VERY user-friendly and efficient; But, it is a very bulky library and not advisable if you are short on resources/time. prefer `csv` in that case

Answer (score 0):

This is not the exact answer but rather steps for you to follow in order to get a solution:

1 Read data from json. some_dict = json.loads(json_string)

2 Appropriate code to get the data from dictionary (sort/ conditions etc) and get that data in a 2D array (list)

3 Save that list as csv: https://realpython.com/python-csv/

Comment: refer official documentations from https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty lazy and like to utilize `pandas` for things like this. It would be something along the lines of

```
import pandas as pd    

file = 'data.json'

with open(file) as j:
    json_data = json.load(j)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(j, orient='index')
df.to_csv("data.csv")
```

Comment: Why not simply [`pd.read_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html)?

Comment: like i mentioned initially