# reading nested json with NONE values in python3

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I have a JSON dataset with 4 columns - data, frame, period and timestamp. 
I have a few records with no values"[]" for the 'data'.

When I try the below solution, it removes the rows containing no values "[]" for the 'data'. I do not want to remove these columns in the results, instead, fill in the missing values with either 0 or NA.

```
Sample data:


{'data': [], 'frame': 807, 'period': 1, 'timestamp': '00:59:49.8'},
{'data': [], 'frame': 808, 'period': 1, 'timestamp': '00:59:49.9'},
{'data': [], 'frame': 809, 'period': 1, 'timestamp': '00:59:50.0'},
{'data': [], 'frame': 810, 'period': 1, 'timestamp': '00:59:50.1'},
{'data': [{'group_name': 'away team',
        'map_x': 175.72,
        'map_y': 210.86,
        'track_id': 4},
       {'group_name': 'away team',
        'map_x': 220.34,
        'map_y': 128.27,
        'track_id': 9},
       {'group_name': 'away team',
        'map_x': 214.22,
        'map_y': 303.3,
        'track_id': 14},
       {'group_name': 'away team',
        'map_x': 225.15,
        'map_y': 106.97,
        'track_id': 15}],
        'frame': 811,
        'period': 1,
        'timestamp': '00:59:50.2'},
 {'data': [{'group_name': 'away team',
        'map_x': 175.48,
        'map_y': 211.89,
        'track_id': 4},
       {'group_name': 'away team',
        'map_x': 219.9,
        'map_y': 128.51,
        'track_id': 9},
       {'group_name': 'away team',
        'map_x': 214.48,
        'map_y': 303.53,
        'track_id': 14},
       {'group_name': 'away team',
        'map_x': 225.1,
        'map_y': 106.0,
        'track_id': 15}],
        'frame': 812,
        'period': 1,
        'timestamp': '00:59:50.3'},
```

Code:

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize    

with open('timestamped_data.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)  

df = json_normalize(data, 'data', ['timestamp', 'frame', 'period'],record_prefix='data_')
```

Output Expected:
[image: output]

Comment: It seems main problem it is to much for `normalize` function, so some preprocessing is necessary. Is possible change json for valid?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do preprocessing before exporting to json :(

Comment: I think before creating DataFrame.

Comment: I tried to filter the missing values first as a separate dataframe and then appended it with the df created by normalizing json. 

I am wondering if there is any better way of handling Null values in json_normaloze.