# Count unique items in JSON file using Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

Given the following JSON file to Pandas (`df = pd.read_json(file)`):

```
[
    {
        "Name": "foo",
        "Details": {
            "Vendor": "Microsoft",
            "Item": "aaa"
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "bar",
        "Details": {
            "Vendor": "Microsoft",
            "Item": "bbb"
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "baz",
        "Details": {
            "Vendor": "Microsoft",
            "Item": "ccc"
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "baz2",
        "Details": {
            "Vendor": "Microsoft",
            "Item": "ccc"
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "qux",
        "Details": {
            "Vendor": "IBM",
            "Item": "aaa"
        }
    }
]
```

I want to perform unique counts of items in the JSON file.  I want to know the number of unique vendors, and the number of unique vendor-item combinations.  With the above JSON, there are 2 unique vendors (Microsoft and IBM) and there are 4 unique vendor-item combinations (baz and baz2 are duplicates).

I believe my current attempts have failed because I have JSON stored inside of my `DataFrame`.

```py
df = pd.read_json(file)
print(df)
```

Outputs:

```
   Name                                 Details
0   foo  {'Vendor': 'Microsoft', 'Item': 'aaa'}
1   bar  {'Vendor': 'Microsoft', 'Item': 'bbb'}
2   baz  {'Vendor': 'Microsoft', 'Item': 'ccc'}
3  baz2  {'Vendor': 'Microsoft', 'Item': 'ccc'}
4   qux        {'Vendor': 'IBM', 'Item': 'aaa'}
```

I've also attempted the following: `print(df.groupby("Details").Vendor.nunique())` which results in the error:

`AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'Vendor'`

Answer (score 1):

A related question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40588852/pandas-read-nested-json). What you are looking for is json_normalize. Little change in the code below.

```py
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize 
a = [
    {
        "Name": "foo",
        "Details": {
            "Vendor": "Microsoft",
            "Item": "aaa"
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "bar",
        "Details": {
            "Vendor": "Microsoft",
            "Item": "bbb"
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "baz",
        "Details": {
            "Vendor": "Microsoft",
            "Item": "ccc"
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "baz2",
        "Details": {
            "Vendor": "Microsoft",
            "Item": "ccc"
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "qux",
        "Details": {
            "Vendor": "IBM",
            "Item": "aaa"
        }
    }
]
Loaded = json_normalize(a)
print(Loaded)
```

Gives me the following output. Now you can do normal aggregation queries over it.
[image: DF ready for aggregation, as seen here]

Comment: This example works when you save the JSON in the scirpt like this.  However, when reading from a file using `df = pd.read_json(file)` I get an error executing `json_normalize` that says: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'"

Comment: So I'm pretty sure you can get around this by first `import json` then `json_normalize(json.loads(filename))`

Answer (score 0):

You may just prepare/filter your JSON data before feeding into `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

data = json.load(open('input.json'))
df = pd.DataFrame([d['Details'] for d in data])
uniq_vendors = df['Vendor'].unique()
uniq_vendor_items = df.drop_duplicates(['Vendor', 'Item'])

print(uniq_vendors)   # output below
['Microsoft' 'IBM']

print(uniq_vendor_items.to_records(index=False))   # output below
[('aaa', 'Microsoft') ('bbb', 'Microsoft') ('ccc', 'Microsoft')
 ('aaa', 'IBM')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach. You may try this.

```py
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import pandas as pd
a = pd.read_json("/PathToYourJSON/TempDelete.json")
a['Vendor']=a['Details'].apply(lambda x: x['Vendor'])
a['Item']=a['Details'].apply(lambda x: x['Item'])
a.drop(columns="Details",inplace=True)
print(a)
```

This gives the output as below. Please let me know if this is what you wanted.

[image: This is the output I see here]

Comment: I've also gotten it working using `groupby`...is there a preference or a downside?  i.e. `unique_vendor_items = df.groupby(["Vendor", "Item"]).count()` then I can  do `print(len(unique_vendor_items))` and I get the same result.

Comment: Will you please paste the print output here (only if you can)?

Comment: @roundtheworld The code that I have written above will only give you the df. The aggregation statistics remains to be computed. You can do it using groupby, as you have already suggested.

Comment: `data = json.load(open(r"test.json", "r", encoding="utf8"))

df = pd.DataFrame([d["Details"] for d in data])

unique_vendor_products = df.drop_duplicates(["Vendor", "Item"])
unique_vendor_products2 = df.groupby(["Vendor", "Item"]).count()

print(unique_vendor_products)
print(f"Count: {len(unique_vendor_products)}")
print("---------------------")
print(unique_vendor_products2)
print(f"Count: {len(unique_vendor_products2)}")`
Note, I tried this on a much larger data set than I provided and got the same count for both methods.