# Pandas read JSON file without headers

Tags: python, pandas

I am curious to know how I can read this JSON file into a Pandas dataframe and set new headers as my source does not have any. I am trying to get date, street, suburb as the headers.

As an example. **Kent Street** is the suburb and **Karawara** is the suburb

```
{
    "25 March 2019": {
        "Albany Highway": ["Maddington", "Cannington"],
        "Kent Street": ["Karawara"],
        "Kitchener Road": ["Alfred Cove"],
        "Alexander Road": ["Rivervale"],
        "Kwinana Freeway": ["Wellard"],
    },
    "26 March 2019": {
        "Great Eastern Highway": ["Sawyers Valley", "Redcliffe"],
        "South Western Highway": ["Armadale", "Wungong"],
        "Great Northern Highway": ["Muchea", "Baskerville"],
        "St Thomas Primary": ["Claremont"],
        "Stirling Highway": ["Claremont"],
        "Grovelands Primary": ["Camillo"],
        "Swan View Senior High": ["Swan View"],
    }
}
```

expect output would be something like;

```
{
    {
        "date": "25 March 2019",
        "street": "Kent Street"
        "suburb": "Karawara"
    }, {
        "date": "26 March 2019",
        "street": "St Thomas Primary"
        "suburb": "Claremont"
    }
}
```

**Rules**
**First** value is always **street**. **Second** value is **suburb**. Some cases there are two suburb. Idealy we would have two rows but if not its mine leaving them as one.

I found similar questions like [Pandas read nested json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40588852/pandas-read-nested-json) but couldn't find any examples where the json file simply had zero headers.

Comment: Hey @AlexandreB. I added a quick example of expected output. Thanks champ.

Comment: How do you select a row ? e.g. that  `St Thomas Primary` is a street and `Claremont` a suburb ?

Comment: Clarify the concrete rule of detecting a street key

Comment: Street key will always be the first column after the date.

Comment: I you are saying "the first column after the date" - that contradicts with your output

Answer (score 3):

if I understand correctly you want the following:

first of all, read the Json file and transform it into a Dictionary

```
import json

 with open('<yourFile>.json', 'r') as JSON:
        json_dict = json.load(JSON)
```

Then, i suppose you have this:

```
x={
    "25 March 2019": {
        "Albany Highway": ["Maddington", "Cannington"],
        "Kent Street": ["Karawara"],
        "Kitchener Road": ["Alfred Cove"],
        "Alexander Road": ["Rivervale"],
        "Kwinana Freeway": ["Wellard"],
    },
    "26 March 2019": {
        "Great Eastern Highway": ["Sawyers Valley", "Redcliffe"],
        "South Western Highway": ["Armadale", "Wungong"],
        "Great Northern Highway": ["Muchea", "Baskerville"],
        "St Thomas Primary": ["Claremont"],
        "Stirling Highway": ["Claremont"],
        "Grovelands Primary": ["Camillo"],
        "Swan View Senior High": ["Swan View"],
    }
}
```

You can do this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([(j,z,h) for i in x.values() for j in x.keys() for h,z in i.items()],columns=['Date','suburb','street'])

print(df)

             Date                       suburb                  street
0   25 March 2019     [Maddington, Cannington]          Albany Highway
1   25 March 2019                   [Karawara]             Kent Street
2   25 March 2019                [Alfred Cove]          Kitchener Road
3   25 March 2019                  [Rivervale]          Alexander Road
4   25 March 2019                    [Wellard]         Kwinana Freeway
5   26 March 2019     [Maddington, Cannington]          Albany Highway
6   26 March 2019                   [Karawara]             Kent Street
7   26 March 2019                [Alfred Cove]          Kitchener Road
8   26 March 2019                  [Rivervale]          Alexander Road
9   26 March 2019                    [Wellard]         Kwinana Freeway
10  25 March 2019  [Sawyers Valley, Redcliffe]   Great Eastern Highway
11  25 March 2019          [Armadale, Wungong]   South Western Highway
12  25 March 2019        [Muchea, Baskerville]  Great Northern Highway
13  25 March 2019                  [Claremont]       St Thomas Primary
14  25 March 2019                  [Claremont]        Stirling Highway
15  25 March 2019                    [Camillo]      Grovelands Primary
16  25 March 2019                  [Swan View]   Swan View Senior High
17  26 March 2019  [Sawyers Valley, Redcliffe]   Great Eastern Highway
18  26 March 2019          [Armadale, Wungong]   South Western Highway
19  26 March 2019        [Muchea, Baskerville]  Great Northern Highway
20  26 March 2019                  [Claremont]       St Thomas Primary
21  26 March 2019                  [Claremont]        Stirling Highway
22  26 March 2019                    [Camillo]      Grovelands Primary
23  26 March 2019                  [Swan View]   Swan View Senior High
```

Alternatively, you can do this like this:

```
dic=[{'date':j,'street':z,'suburb':h} for i in x.values() for j in x.keys() for h,z in i.items()]

dic

[{'date': '25 March 2019',
  'street': ['Maddington', 'Cannington'],
  'suburb': 'Albany Highway'},
 {'date': '25 March 2019', 'street': ['Karawara'], 'suburb': 'Kent Street'},
 {'date': '25 March 2019',
  'street': ['Alfred Cove'],
  'suburb': 'Kitchener Road'},
 {'date': '25 March 2019',
  'street': ['Rivervale'],
  'suburb': 'Alexander Road'},
 {'date': '25 March 2019', 'street': ['Wellard'], 'suburb': 'Kwinana Freeway'},
 {'date': '26 March 2019',
  'street': ['Maddington', 'Cannington'],
  'suburb': 'Albany Highway'},
 {'date': '26 March 2019', 'street': ['Karawara'], 'suburb': 'Kent Street'},
 {'date': '26 March 2019',
  'street': ['Alfred Cove'],
  'suburb': 'Kitchener Road'},
 {'date': '26 March 2019',
  'street': ['Rivervale'],
  'suburb': 'Alexander Road'}
```

...

as lists of dictionaries. Now you can transform it into dataframe like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(d)

             date                       street                  suburb
0   25 March 2019     [Maddington, Cannington]          Albany Highway
1   25 March 2019                   [Karawara]             Kent Street
2   25 March 2019                [Alfred Cove]          Kitchener Road
3   25 March 2019                  [Rivervale]          Alexander Road
4   25 March 2019                    [Wellard]         Kwinana Freeway
5   26 March 2019     [Maddington, Cannington]          Albany Highway
6   26 March 2019                   [Karawara]             Kent Street
7   26 March 2019                [Alfred Cove]          Kitchener Road
8   26 March 2019                  [Rivervale]          Alexander Road
9   26 March 2019                    [Wellard]         Kwinana Freeway
10  25 March 2019  [Sawyers Valley, Redcliffe]   Great Eastern Highway
11  25 March 2019          [Armadale, Wungong]   South Western Highway
12  25 March 2019        [Muchea, Baskerville]  Great Northern Highway
13  25 March 2019                  [Claremont]       St Thomas Primary
14  25 March 2019                  [Claremont]        Stirling Highway
15  25 March 2019                    [Camillo]      Grovelands Primary
16  25 March 2019                  [Swan View]   Swan View Senior High
17  26 March 2019  [Sawyers Valley, Redcliffe]   Great Eastern Highway
18  26 March 2019          [Armadale, Wungong]   South Western Highway
19  26 March 2019        [Muchea, Baskerville]  Great Northern Highway
20  26 March 2019                  [Claremont]       St Thomas Primary
21  26 March 2019                  [Claremont]        Stirling Highway
22  26 March 2019                    [Camillo]      Grovelands Primary
23  26 March 2019                  [Swan View]   Swan View Senior High
```