# How to Read Nested Json file in PandasSql

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandasql

I used to have a simple row and column format in table and was  reading it by pandassql .

but if you have structure like below and  want to get age>10 from this , how do I get it using pandassql?

```
  [  {
    "response":{
      "version":"1.1",
      "token":"dsfgf",
       "body":{
         "customer":{
             "customer_id":"1234567",
             "verified":"true"
           },
         "contact":{
             "email":"mr@abc.com",
             "mobile_number":"0123456789"
          },
         "personal":{
             "gender": "m",
             "title":"Dr.",
             "last_name":"Muster",
             "first_name":"Max",
             "family_status":"single",
             "dob":"1985-12-23",
         }
       }
     } ]
```

Comment: there is an error with the json.  need to remove the first bracket.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas read nested json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40588852/pandas-read-nested-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answered here:

[Pandas read nested json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40588852/pandas-read-nested-json)

You can use `json_normalize`

There is also a full description of the dame issue here:

https://medium.com/swlh/converting-nested-json-structures-to-pandas-dataframes-e8106c59976e