# Convert deeply subnested JSON data to a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

How do I convert this JSON data (https://api.llama.fi/summary/fees/lyra?dataType=dailyFees) to a pandas dataframe? https://data.page/json/csv does this extremely well when uploading a file, how can I modify my script to accomplish this?

```
# Initialize an empty list to store the exploded and normalized dataframes
df_list = []
# Iterate over the columns of the dataframe
for col in df.columns:
  # Check if the column contains lists
  if df[col].apply(type).eq(list).any():
    # Explode the column
    df1 = df.explode(col, ignore_index=True)
    # Normalize the dataframe
    df2 = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(df1.to_json(orient="records")))
    df_list.append(df2)   
    result = pd.concat(df_list) 
  else:
    result = df_list.append(df) 
    result = pd.concat(df_list)
# Check if the dataframe contains any columns with dicts
if result.applymap(type).eq(list).any().any():
# Get the labels of the columns with dicts
  list_columns = result.applymap(type).eq(list).any().index[result.applymap(type).eq(list).any()].tolist()
  result = result.drop(list_columns, axis=1)   
else:
   result
result
```

Comment: are you expecting 1 row and 23 columns? If so, does this answer your question? [Pandas read nested json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40588852/pandas-read-nested-json)

Comment: Take a look at [`pandas.json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html#pandas-json-normalize). If it doesn't produce the output you want, you'll need to write your own formatter.

Comment: Please don't use links to code, data, etc, use the editor to include sample data inline in your question. Then, also include the results you want from the sample data.

Comment: Why do none of your previous questions have accepted answers?

Answer (score 1):

Using [json.normalize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html#pandas-json-normalize):

```
import json

import pandas as pd
import requests


url = "https://api.llama.fi/summary/fees/lyra?dataType=dailyFees"

with requests.Session() as request:
    response = request.get(url)
if response.status_code != 200:
    print(response.raise_for_status())

data = json.loads(response.text)

df = (pd
      .json_normalize(data=data)
      .explode("totalDataChart")
      .explode("totalDataChartBreakdown")
      .explode("totalDataChartBreakdown")
      .explode("audit_links")
      .explode("totalDataChart")
      .explode("chains")
      ).reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df["totalDataChartBreakdown"])).drop("totalDataChartBreakdown", axis=1)
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(".").str[-1]
print(df)
```